Is there any impact for the existing values if we change the length of the percent fields?
I have field percent(18,0) and now i am updating the length to (17,1).Is there any impact for the existing values (having 18 digits) in the records?
Please help
Thanks,

Number fields store data with very high precision. Changing the length or precision won't affect any records in the database. Lowering the length won't affect the display, but changing the precision will cause the UI to round the numbers to the new precision. However, formulas will use the full value that's stored in the database, not the display value, and the number will be stored in the original precision until a user attempts to edit the value, in which case an error may be thrown if the new value isn't inside the valid range for the field. In summary, it won't affect any existing data or cause any data loss.

If you have records with values that use all 18 digits, these values will be affected. Salesforce will attempt to truncate the value to fit the new field size, which results in data loss for the last digit.
For values that do not use all 18 digits, Salesforce will round the value to the nearest tenth due to the new decimal place.
It is important to note that Salesforce does not automatically delete or alter data when you change field lengths.
However, you may encounter errors if existing data does not conform to the new field specifications.
To avoid data loss, consider creating a new field with the desired length and using a data migration strategy to move and adjust the values from the old field to the new one. This way, you can ensure that all data conforms to the new field specifications without unexpected truncation or rounding.

This is incorrect. Number fields don't work this way.
